# Can I use an isolated DC-DC module with breaking its isolation?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ground, isolation

I'm in need of a DC-DC module on a project.

The DC-DC module I have is [here.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/DCW12C-15/7702729)

This is an isolated module but in my situation its input and output is going to be on the same ground.

Will it cause a problem if I break the isolation on this module?

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not cause problems. It simply means the isolation is not needed at all and 0V between input and output is within the 1500V that it can handle.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally OK, no harm will be made.

Still, consider whether this is the right way to use it. A common application for isolated power supplies is breaking ground loops- or in other words organizing currents in such a way that they will flow where required, not just randomly.

Often people prefer to save the 2 dollars of the isolated power supply and hope it will work out somehow (and usually it's fine), but when you have an opportunity to use isolation "for free", think about the current return path, make it perfect, not just good enough.